# Trying to request array like variables

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, html-input

I have a form where I use several variables sort of like an array, and on one of my servers (godaddy) I do not have to request the variables and it works fine.  I have to change servers shortly, and I need a work around so I can request these variables

I have 12 input areas like

```
<input name="sd[1]" type="text" id="sd1" size='10' value='<?echo$sd[1];?>'/>
<input name="sd[2]" type="text" id="sd2" size='10' value='<?echo$sd[2];?>'/>
...
<input name="sd[12]" type="text" id="sd12" size='10' value='<?echo$sd[12];?>'/>
```

I need to be able to request each of the sd[#] variables, but everything I have tried does not work.

I have tried things like

```
for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){
$sd[$i]= $_POST['sd']["$i"];
}
```

and

```
for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){
$sd[$i]= $_POST['sd[$i]'];
}
```

and

```
$sd[1]= $_POST['sd[1]'];
```

I would appreciate any help that you have to offer.
Thanks,
Kelly

Comment: Check what `$_POST` contains, see what `var_dump($_POST);` gives you.

Comment: As I state below, your new host may not like the short PHP tags. If this is so then you are not even passing the values through. I agree, you should try to dump the $_POST array to check

Comment: Your `for` loop fails because of `$_POST['sd[$i]'];` you can't get reference to the variable `$i` with single quotation marks. Which should be `$_POST['sd'][$i]` anyways

Answer (score 2):

The grouping name `name="sd[]"` already returns an array, being the number inside the `[]` as the index. Treat the array as you normally would.

`foreach` is much suited for this task:

```
$sd = $_POST['sd'];
foreach($sd as $key => $value) {
    // $key is integer inside name[1] or name[2], and so on
    echo $key;
    echo $value;
}
```

Actually, the loop with another assignment is superfluous, since this array already represents what you want.

```
$sd = $_POST['sd']; // contains the key pair values 1 => the corresponding echoed value from the form, and so on... 
echo $sd[12];
```

Comment: of course, if your array contains both numeric and associative indices, then it wouldn't make sense to use `for`  anymore, but in this case, (my preference) i'd use `foreach`, i didn't said anything about `for` not going to materialize in this particular situation

Answer (score 0):

Use this example:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['sd'])) {
  for($i = 1; $i <= count($_POST['sd']); $i++) {
      echo $_POST['sd'][$i] . "<br>";
  }   
}   


?>

<form action='' method='POST'>
<input name="sd[1]" type="text" id="sd1" size='10' value='1'/>
<input name="sd[2]" type="text" id="sd1" size='10' value='2'/>
<input name="sd[3]" type="text" id="sd1" size='10' value='3'/>
<input type=submit value='Send'>
</form>
```

Or you can use this code, in your html code you can set the input name like this `name="sd[]"` in this case the first element is `0` see the code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['sd'])) {
  for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['sd']); $i++) {
      echo $_POST['sd'][$i] . "<br>";
  }   
}   


?>

<form action='' method='POST'>
<input name="sd[]" type="text" id="sd1" size='10' value='1'/>
<input name="sd[]" type="text" id="sd1" size='10' value='2'/>
<input name="sd[]" type="text" id="sd1" size='10' value='3'/>
<input type=submit value='Send'>
</form>
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quotes around "$i".

```
for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++){
   $sd[$i]= $_POST['sd'][$i];
}
```

Comment: A down vote on my answer is poor form. It works. I see down votes for everyone but the top voted answer. No need to take points from people if their answers work.

Answer (score 0):

First you should not use short tags for your PHP.

```
<? is bad, <?php is good.
```

The short tag option is turned off by default on most hosts.

Second you should be able to access the values like this.

```
$sd[1]= $_POST['sd'][1];
```

or even like this iff you need to loop

```
foreach($_POST['sd'] as $key => $value){
    // $key is the number: 1-12
    // $value is what is held in it. ex sd[1]
}
```